# Gradle configuration "builtBy" a task

Tags: gradle, dependencies, directed-acyclic-graphs

Consider the following buildscript where

- `addToMyConfig` adds a dependency to a [Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) named `myConfig`
- `useMyConfig` consumes the `myConfig` [Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) and forces it to [resolve()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html#resolve--)

```grovy
configurations {
    myConfig
}
task addToMyConfig {
    doLast {
        println "Doing some work"
        dependencies {
            myConfig 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
        }
    }
}
task useMyConfig {
    doLast {
        println "myConfig = $configurations.myConfig.files"
    }
}
```

Question: Is there a way to fire `addToMyConfig` every time `configurations.myConfig` is resolved without adding a task dependency where `useMyConfig` depends on `addToMyConfig`?

I would like to say:

```groovy
configurations.myConfig.builtBy addToMyConfig
```

** I do NOT want to say **

```groovy
useMyConfig.dependsOn addToMyConfig
```

I want to avoid `useMyConfig.dependsOn addToMyConfig` because there may be many tasks which consume `configurations.myConfig`

Note: There is a [ConfigurableFileCollection.builtBy(Object... tasks)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/ConfigurableFileCollection.html#builtBy-java.lang.Object...-) method which would solve my problem, if only it existed on the [Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html) interface (configuration extends [FileCollection](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html))

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need a `task` to populate the `configuration` with dependencies?

[`Configuration#withDependencies`](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html#withDependencies-org.gradle.api.Action-) can be used to add dependencies during resolution. Like this:

```
configurations {
  myConfig
}

configurations.myConfig.withDependencies {deps ->
  println "Resolving dependencies"
  dependencies {
    myConfig "log4j:log4j:1.2.17"
  }
}

task useMyConfig {
    doLast {
        println "myConfig = $configurations.myConfig.files"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Whilst this might seem to solve the problem, there is "work" involved with resolving the dependencies. I'd like to take advantage of Gradle's input/output hashing so that I can benefit from `UP-TO_DATE` checking. I want to split this into two tasks, the first task does some "work" and creates a gradle script. The second "applies" the gradle script.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible out-of-the-box. A task runs at most once.

When you call configurations.myConfig, you are calling a dynamic property added to the [ConfigurationContainer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ConfigurationContainer.html)

Using groovy, it should be possible to override the configurationContainers' behavior via the metaClass. You would be invoking a function here, not a task.

Comment: The "task runs at most once" rule is absolutely fine. I want the task to run only once per build (assuming configuration resolution required in the build). As with @eloff's answer I don't want to run a function, I want to run a task which does some "work" so I want to use input/output hashing and `UP-TO-DATE` functionality provided by tasks

Answer (score 1):

this is what you want i think:

```
def files = project.files(your,produced,files)
files.builtBy addToMyConfig
myConfig.dependencies.add(project.dependencies.create(files))
```

Comment: sorry i'm one year late lol... however you solve it, it's individual dependencies -not configurations- that are builtBy. makes sense because deps are units of production while configs are units of consumption. thank you!

Comment: @Lanchon have you tried this code? I cannot get it working (Gradle 5.4.1). The `addToMyConfig` task is not executed when `myConfig` is requested.

Comment: Finally, I've discovered an interesting thing: configuration resolution itself doesn't take configuration dependencies into account. But if `useMyConfig.dependsOn configurations.myConfig`, dependency on `addToMyConfig` is propagated to `useMyConfig` and all works as expected.

Comment: with `useMyConfig.dependsOn configurations.myConfig` you are explicitly telling gradle to resolve myConfig before executing task useMyConfig. this is an unusual thing to do; why it is needed in your case depends on how you wrote useMyConfig. not to imply that something is 'wrong', but there is probably a more idiomatic way to write the task. if the task inputs depend on the config in a gradle-traceable way, gradle will create an implicit dependsOn relationship for you.

Comment: however, this matter is unrelated the original question on how to trigger a task on config resolution. (TL;DR you can't, AFAIK, but you can trigger a task on dependency resolution instead.) please mark as answered if applicable, thanks!